# how can I quiet a 'chirping' ventilation fan motor blade?

Tags: noise, hvac

I have a 2006 VW Golf and the internal fan motor that blows the a/c & heat will start to 'chirp' (sound something like a bird singing) randomly.

I believe the fan blade needs to be lubricated, but I have no clue how to go about accessing the blade's location since it is somewhere inside the dashboard.

Is there any way to spray something like WD40 inside the air intake for the ventilation system to calm the chirps?

Comment: turn up the radio :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The single most common reason is something, often leaves or the like, finding their way into the fan. Regardless, you really need to remove the fan to fix the problem. If you don't know where it is then it's time to get that workshop manual you should already have to do regular maintenance and repair on the vehicle.

once the fan has been removed rig up some wires so that you can run the fan while it is outside the car. Most times just doing that will instantly reveal the problem if it's not caused by foreign matter.

Definitely do not spray anything into the vents. It's not going to fix your problem and is more than likely to create one or more new ones. e.g. WD40 coming back out of the vents into the interior of the car, where it will leave stains.

Comment: Good point about checking for leaves, this is indeed a common source of noises in fans. If you do get the fan out and find foreign matter, be sure to dig around as much as you can where the fan comes out to check for other stuff hiding in there. Also, check if you have a dust filter. This may have a ton of leaves around it if it has been neglected.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't spray oil into the vents. It'll likely make the air stink for awhile without helping anything.

Many times the fan is accessible by removing a panel under the passenger side dash (right above where their feet would be). This may be the same location as a dust filter on some cars. If the fan is accessible in this area, you can try some lubricant.

You may have to keep lubricating it over time, and it's up to you whether it's worth the hassle vs. paying for/installing a new fan for a longer-term solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I tried lubrication several times but that didn't work. I ended up taking it out and just replacing it. Not that expensive. Do it yourself.